# Editing a plist from within local bash script folder

Tags: objective-c, macos, bash, plist

I am trying to edit a plist using a script, which determines the local folder where the script is run from. What I am running into is a blank plist. Objective-C wrap-around's would also be an option, but I don't get the expected edit of the plist from it.

It works as expected when run individually without the second sed pipe command at the end, and passing it from running the script in the shell and then adding it.

The whole cat MyPlist.plist etc. lines work as expected when run individually from the shell.

Output: None, it just runs

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh    

# scriptname is the full path of the script location.
scriptpath=`echo $scriptname | sed 's/MyScript.sh/\//g'`
cd $scriptpath
cd ..
cat MyPlist.plist | sed 's/<\/dict>/<key>My\ Plist\ Setting<\/key><string>1<\/string><\/dict>/g' > MyPlist.plist;
```

Comment: Perhaps you can reduce your shell script to a smaller example that still demonstrates the problem. - Also the input, output and expected output would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Martin R, it's done, hopefully that helps.

Comment: Are you sure that the current working directory is correct (i.e. the one containing "MyPlist.plist") when the final line is executed? Perhaps add a `pwd` call to check.

Comment: @Marin R, yes as the script works perfectly without NSTask, and the plist file gets edited, but it just returns an empty plist.

Comment: I don't know why that should happen. - But instead of sed I would use /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy to manipulate property lists. See "man PlistBuddy".

Comment: Thanks @Martin R PlistBuddy seems to only allow interactive mode, but this problem requires the task to be run programmatically.

Comment: PlistBuddy can be used as command line tool, e.g. `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :KEY VALUE" /path/to/plistfile`

Comment: @Martin R thanks so much, that solved it! Can you create an answer so I can mark it as accepted, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `sed` I recommend to use `PlistBuddy` to modify property list files,
which is less error-prone:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :KEY VALUE" /path/to/plistfile
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dirname`, that is much easier and works for me.

Call it like this:
`scriptpath="$(dirname $0)"`

Or another option is this:
`scriptpath="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"`

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Dominik Hadl, the second command is the one working on OS X, have been trying to find it for a long time. The script works in its basics, but not as the desired NSTask.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, because it came closer to a solution, however the problem couldn't be solved.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
cat MyPlist.plist | sed 's/<\/dict>/<key>My\ Plist\ Setting<\/key><string>1<\/string><\/dict>/g' > MyPlist.plist;
```

seems unreliable to me. There's a race condition as to whether the `cat` subprocess has opened the pre-existing MyPlist.plist file before the shell opens the same file for the redirected output of the `sed` command. The shell would presumably open it with `O_TRUNC` to discard its existing contents and start it from scratch. That might happen before `cat` reads it. (The commands on either side of the pipe ('`|`') are run simultaneously, not serially.)

You should use a second file temporarily and then replace the original with the result if the commands were successful.

Comment: I used sed infile > outfile, it still returns an empty plist.